# How can I change cursor shape in tty?

Tags: linux, console, virtual-consoles

I want to change my tty cursor shape underline to block. I tried this:

```
if [[ "$TERM" == "linux" ]]; then
    echo -e -n "\x1b[\x32 q";
fi
```

It's working on gnome-terminal but on tty.

Answer (score 3):

Look at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/vga-softcursor.html :

```
The cursor appearance is controlled by a ``<ESC>[?1;2;3c`` escape sequence
where 1, 2 and 3 are parameters described below. If you omit any of them,
they will default to zeroes.
first Parameter
        specifies cursor size::

                0=default
                1=invisible
                2=underline,
                ...
                8=full block
                + 16 if you want the software cursor to be applied
                + 32 if you want to always change the background color
                + 64 if you dislike having the background the same as the
                     foreground.

        Highlights are ignored for the last two flags.

second parameter
        selects character attribute bits you want to change
        (by simply XORing them with the value of this parameter). On standard
        VGA, the high four bits specify background and the low four the
        foreground. In both groups, low three bits set color (as in normal
        color codes used by the console) and the most significant one turns
        on highlight (or sometimes blinking -- it depends on the configuration
        of your VGA).

third parameter
        consists of character attribute bits you want to set.

        Bit setting takes place before bit toggling, so you can simply clear a
        bit by including it in both the set mask and the toggle mask.

Examples
--------

To get normal blinking underline, use::

        echo -e '\033[?2c'

To get blinking block, use::

        echo -e '\033[?6c'

To get red non-blinking block, use::

        echo -e '\033[?17;0;64c'
```

Comment: Can you explain the perametres please? It seems confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf '\033[?112c'
```

The `112` (`0x70`) means "soft block cursor" (`0x10`) + "change the background" (`0x20`) + "foreground different from the background" (`0x40`).

That should ensure that the cursor is always visible, no matter the attributes of the character cell at that position.

And if you don't want that `vim` or `emacs` reset the cursor to the default "blinking underline" upon exiting, also do this:

```
infocmp linux |
sed 's/cnorm=[^,]*/cnorm=\\033[25h\\033[?112c/' |
tic -
```

---

That escape also takes another two parameters, which allow you to modify the color and attributes of the character cell (before the fg/bg differentiating transformations mentioned above): the second tells which bits should be *set*, and the first which bits should be *toggled*, with the second applied *before* the first. The meaning of the bits is that of the [VGA attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_text_mode#Text_buffer), not that of curses/ANSI colors. For example (assuming the default palette, etc):

```
# usage: set_cursor attributes
set_cursor(){ printf '\033[?112;%d;255c' "$((~$1 & 255))"; }
           # set + toggle = clear all bits except those present in the argument

set_cursor $((0x80  | 0x8   | 0x40   | 0x6     ))
           #  hi bg | hi fg | red bg | brown fg = "yellow" fg upon "pink" bg
```

Instead of trying to make sense of stackexchange answers, better have a look at the source: [`add_softcursor()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.9/source/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c#L869) and [`\e[?c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.9/source/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c#L2336) parsing.

Comment: OK, that made the cursor white block but, can you please explain the parameters? It would be great.